# Condition on the index of an element $a_{i,j}$

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, function-construction, index

This question may seem to be easy. But I did not find the right way after several attempts

I need to put a condition in general for $a_{i,j}$ ,If the `i` is bigger than `j` puts $a_{j,i}$, other way puts $a_{i,j}$.

```
If[i > j, Subscript[a, j, i], Subscript[a, i, j]]
```

> $\text{If}\left[i>j,a_{j,i},a_{i,j}\right]$

But I do not know how to implement it on a function. How it applies to a function as in the following example.

For example

If I have the following function

```
f= Subscript[a, 1, 3] Subscript[a, 3, 2] +Subscript[a, 1, 3] Subscript[a, 2,3] -Subscript[a, 5, 2] Subscript[a, 1, 2] Subscript[a, 3, 2]
```

> $f=a_{1,3} a_{3,2}+a_{1,3} a_{2,3}-a_{5,2} a_{1,2} a_{3,2}$

This condition will work on turning index as follows,

> $a_{3,2} \Rightarrow a_{2,3}$
>
> $a_{5,2} \Rightarrow a_{2,5}$

then, we get f as following,

> $f=2a_{1,3} a_{2,3}-a_{1,2} a_{2,3} a_{2,5}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f = 
  Subscript[a, 1, 3] Subscript[a, 3, 2] + 
  Subscript[a, 1, 3] Subscript[a, 2, 3] - 
  Subscript[a, 5, 2] Subscript[a, 1, 2] Subscript[a, 3, 2];

f /. Subscript[a_, i_, j_] /; i > j :> Subscript[a, j, i]
```

[image]

If you want to do this repeatedly you can define a function:

```
rep[fn_] := fn /. Subscript[a_, i_, j_] /; i > j :> Subscript[a, j, i]
```

Now it's just

```
rep @ f
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using `Subscript` if you can, and simply use `a[1,2]` etc. instead. Then you can define

```
a[i_, j_] /; i>j := a[j,i]
```

Now

```
a[1, 3] a[3, 2] + a[1, 3] a[2, 3] - a[5, 2] a[1, 2] a[3, 2]
```

returns

```
2 a[1, 3] a[2, 3] - a[1, 2] a[2, 3] a[2, 5]
```

An advantage of doing it this way is that things are transformed automatically, with no need to replace expressions repeatedly, applying functions to expressions etc.

Comment: One can even add `MakeBoxes[a[x__], _] := ToBoxes @ Subscript[a, x]` to get the (apparently) desired output format.